# Why my service does not share data between controllers?

Tags: angularjs, factory

I built a factory to get Data from the Database and pass to all controllers in my application like this:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('appContacts')
        .factory('dataService', ['$http', dataService]);

    function dataService($http) {

        return {
            getCurrentOrganization: getCurrentOrganization,
        };

        function getCurrentOrganization(id) {

            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/organization/' + id + '/contacts'
            })
        }
    }

})();
```

And I have a view like this:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="contactController">
     <a ui-sref="organization({Id: organization.id})" ng-click="vm.setCurrentOrganization(organization)"> {{organization.organizationName }}</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

That link redirect from a view the view contactsView.html to a detail view organizationDetail.html managed by a second controller:

```
  ....
.state("home", {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "views/contactsView.html",
        controller: "contactsController",
         controllerAs: "vm"
    })
    .state("organization", {
        url: "/organization/:Id",
        templateUrl: "views/organizationDetail.html",
        params: { Id: null },
        controller: "organizationsController",
        controllerAs: "vm"
    })
...
```

My problem is that I get the data, I see in the console, but when the new URL comes into place, the Data is gone and the view is shown empty.

How could I use the data produced in the factory in the second Controller?

EDIT:

Here are the Controllers:

```
//organizationsController.js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('appContacts')
        .controller('organizationsController', function organizationsController(dataService) {

            var vm = this;

            vm.setCurrentOrganization = function (organization) {
                vm.theOrganization = organization;
                vm.visible = true;

  dataService.getCurrentOrganization(vm.theOrganization.id).then(function (result) {
                    vm.organizationData = result.data;

                }, function () {
                    vm.errorMessage = "Failed to load" + Error;
                });
            }
    });
})();
```

And the contactsController:

```
//contactsController.js

(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('appContacts')
        .controller('contactsController', function contactsController(dataService) {

            var vm = this;
            vm.visible = false;

            activate();

            function activate() {
                dataService.getAllContacts().then(function (result) {
                    vm.allcontacts = result.data;
                }, function () {
                    vm.errorMessage = "Failed to load" + Error;
                });

                dataService.getAllOrganizations().then(function (result) {
                    vm.organizations = result.data;
                }, function () {
                    vm.errorMessage = "Failed to load" + Error;
                });
            }
    });
})();
```

The problem is that I click the llink in the view A (contactsView.html/ContactsViewController) and I should end in the VIEW B (OrganizationDetails.html/organizationController), using the Data fetch in the service.

Comment: can you share code for the controllers as well?

Comment: Have you tried using $rootScope or ngStorage ?

Comment: @Pradeepb I added the controllers.

Comment: The firstView has a list of companies. When I click the link I posted, I pass the object (organization) to the controller and set it as currrentOrganization. With that I make a query looking for the contacts that belongs to that company.
The result is correct, as I can see in the console. Just in the last step, when the view changes from contactView.Html to Organizationsdetails.Html, the data is gone

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong here

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="contactController">
     <a ui-sref="organization({Id: organization.id})" ng-click="vm.setCurrentOrganization(organization)"> {{organization.organizationName }}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your `contactController` does not have the function `setCurrentOrganization`. Instead its in another controller. you can remove the code `ng-click="vm.setCurrentOrganization(organization)"` from the HTML. and read the `id` using `$stateParams` in the `organizationsController`. After getting the `id`, use it call the service as below:

```
dataService.getCurrentOrganization(id).then(function (result) {
        vm.organizationData = result.data;
    }, function () {
      vm.errorMessage = "Failed to load" + Error;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, What you say is logic. I will give it a try

Comment: sure. Accept the answer once you succeed.

Comment: Thanks man! You saved my life.
By accept the answer do you mean press the UP arrow?

Comment: You can see the tick arrow i guess. and you are welcome :)